# RxJS map operator vs destructuring performance

Tags: rxjs, reactivex

Personally I would consider #2 bad practice in terms of `rxjs` - am I right?
Which of ways below is more preferable in terms of performance and why?

```
source$.pipe(
   map(s => s.someKey)
).subscribe(someValue => {
   workWithData(someValue)
})
```

or

```
source$.subscribe(({someValue}) => {
   workWithData(someValue)
})
```

Comment: In terms of performance the second one is definitely better. Destructuring is always faster than using operators.

Comment: @martin can you give any advices what to read on this? I know `useSelector` from redux doesnt recommend to pull the whole state and then destructure - it recommends to map it instead

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that performance is the main question here, it's more about your intention. The second one is better because you call less functions.

If you plan to use the mapped observable stream in other parts of your application, you should use the first one, like this:

```js
const sourceKeys$ = source$.pipe(
   map(s => s.someKey)
);
sourceKeys.subscribe(someValue => {
   workWithData(someValue)
})
```

If you will not need the `sourceKeys$` as an observable, you can do all side effects and data operations in the `subscribe` block.